# Картинка на пересечении двух блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

[image: Как правильно сверстать такой блок?]

Подскажите, как правильно сверстать блок таким образом, чтобы на пересечении двух блоков была картинка? Если верстать через position: absolute, то при адаптиве на других разрешениях придется вручную подгонять положение этой картинки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так?

```css
.zzz {
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.aaa {
  clip-path: ellipse(30% 50% at 30% 50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.25);
  min-height: inherit;
}

.bbb {
  clip-path: ellipse(30% 50% at 70% 50%);
  height: 100%;
  min-height: inherit;
  background-image: url('https://www.textures.com/system/gallery/photos/Fabric/Plain%20Fabric/120847/FabricPlain0147_3_350.jpg');
}

.ccc,
.ddd {
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top:0;
  width:60%;
}

.ccc {left:0;}
.ddd {right:0;}
```

```html
<div class="zzz">
  <div class="aaa">
    <div class="bbb"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="ccc"></div>
  <div class="ddd"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Решение SVG

Работает во всех браузерах, решение адаптивно

С помощью pattern заполняется изображением левый эллипс
С помощью маски, которая применена к правому эллипсу вырезается часть левого эллипса

- Одна пара эллипсов

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 150" >  
         <defs>
           <pattern id="patt"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> 
             <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF6Xi.jpg" width="100%" heigh="100%" />
           </pattern> 
           <mask id="mask"> 
             <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />           
            <ellipse cx="230" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40" fill="black" stroke="black" />
           </mask>
         </defs>

<ellipse fill="url(#patt)" cx="100" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40"  stroke="black" />  
  <ellipse mask="url(#mask)" fill="white" cx="100" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40"  stroke="black" /> 
 
 <ellipse cx="230" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Две пары эллипсов (как в вопросе)

```html
<style>
.container {
width:50vw;
height:auto;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 150" >  
         <defs>
           <pattern id="patt"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> 
             <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF6Xi.jpg" width="100%" heigh="100%" />
           </pattern> 
           <mask id="mask"> 
             <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />           
            <ellipse cx="230" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40" fill="black" stroke="black" />
           </mask>
         </defs>

<ellipse fill="url(#patt)" cx="100" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40"  stroke="black" />  
  <ellipse mask="url(#mask)" fill="white" cx="100" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40"  stroke="black" /> 
 
 <ellipse cx="230" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>  
</div>  
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 150" >  
         <defs>
           <pattern id="patt2"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> 
             <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/g29kk.jpg" width="100%" heigh="100%" />
           </pattern> 
           <mask id="mask"> 
             <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />           
            <ellipse cx="230" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40" fill="black" stroke="black" />
           </mask>
         </defs>

<ellipse fill="url(#patt2)" cx="100" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40"  stroke="black" />  
  <ellipse mask="url(#mask)" fill="white" cx="100" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40"  stroke="black" /> 
 
 <ellipse cx="230" cy="50" rx="90" ry="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>    
</div>
```

### UPDATE

Вариант с адаптивным текстом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:auto;
background:#FFE7D7;
}
.txt {
fill:#434238;
font-family:serif;
font-size:10px;
}
.txtN {
 fill:black;
font-family:sans-serif;
font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 450 200" >  
         <defs>
           <pattern id="patt"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%"> 
             <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF6Xi.jpg" width="100%" heigh="100%" />
           </pattern> 
           <mask id="mask"> 
             <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />           
            <ellipse cx="310" cy="50" rx="120" ry="40" fill="black" stroke="black" />
           </mask>
         </defs>

<ellipse fill="url(#patt)" cx="120" cy="50" rx="120" ry="40"  stroke="black" />  
  <ellipse mask="url(#mask)" fill="#FFE7D7" cx="120" cy="50" rx="120" ry="40"  stroke="black" /> 
 
 <ellipse cx="310" cy="50" rx="120" ry="40" fill="none" stroke="black" />
      <!-- Для левого эллипса -->
  <g>
 <text class="txtN" x="20" y="30" font-size="18px"  >01. </text>
     <text class="txt" x="50" y="30"  >Равным образом постоянный </text> 
      <text class="txt" x="24" y="43"  >количественный рост и сфера нашей </text>   
        <text class="txt" x="30" y="56" font-size="10px" ><tspan style="fill:#FF872C">активности позволяет</tspan> выполнять </text> 
         <text class="txt" x="36" y="67"  >важные задания по разработке </text>     
          <text class="txt" x="48" y="77"  >модели развития. Товарищи! </text>  
   </g>       
        <!-- Для правого эллипса -->
  <g>
   <text class="txtN"  x="390" y="30">02. </text> 
    <text class="txt"  x="250" y="30"  >Таким образом постоянное </text> 
      <text class="txt"  x="244" y="43" >инфорационно-пропогандискское</text>   
        <text class="txt"  x="250" y="56"  >обеспечение нашей деятельности</text> 
         <text class="txt"  x="244" y="67"  >требует от нас <tspan style="fill:#FF872C">анализа позиций</tspan>  </text>        
          <text  class="txt"  x="252" y="77" font-size="10px" >занимаемых участниками </text>   
   </g>       
      
</svg>  
</div>
```

Comment: В вопросе еще текст есть)) И хорошо бы вмещающий его блок подстраивался под объем текста. А так верстка принятого ответа, например, ломается при добавлении текста. А тогда для чего это все? Это фоновая картинка или что?

Comment: @Leonid согласен, не стал сам писать об этом, чтобы не сочли, что оспариваю принятый ответ. Хотя у автора вопроса было основное требование - адаптивность

Comment: @Leonid А текст добавить оч. легко и он будет подстраиваться под эллипсы. Просто поленился немного, зная, что всё равно выберут CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того как оно себя должно вести при уменьшении дизайна к мобильному устройству. Это надо у дизайнера спрашивать. * Я бы не цеплялся за "оба блока" а отталкивался бы от правых блоков. Ну и разумеется [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) в помощь